# nextjs 13 and apollo client --TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'watchQuery')

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, next.js13

I'm trying out the new nextjs 13 (where everything is in the app directory instead of pages directory). I have to use the "use client" directive because I'm also using react-redux in the project.

I'm trying to setup and test apollo-client for data fetching.  In testing apollo I'm following the setup instructions here:
https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/how-to-use-apollo-client-with-next-js-13/
like this:

client.js:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from "@apollo/client";

let client = ApolloClient;

export const getClient = () => {
  //create a new client if there's no existing one
  //or if we are running on the server
  if (!client || typeof window === "undefined") {
    client = new ApolloClient({
      link: new HttpLink({
        uri: "https://main--time-pav6zq.apollographos.net/graphql",
      }),
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
  } //end if
  return client;
};
```

and this:
app/page.js

```
"use client";
import { getClient, clientNoCache } from "./client";
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const query = gql`
  query Now {
    now(id: "1")
  }
`;

export default function Page() {
  const client = getClient();
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(query, { client });

...etc
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'watchQuery')  23 | export default function Page() {
  24 | const client = getClient();
> 25 | const { loading, data } = useQuery(query, { client });
```

I followed the instructions exactly.  What is wrong?